Change toUpperCase() all except those within single quotes
Over the last couple of days I have read through many similar questions but none that actually answers what I am looking for. Hence , posting this question.
I have a string, for example:
    String myString = "Rule2 = if(event = 'Veteran''s Day', 'Day 1', 'Day 2', Measure1.Lag)"; 

I want this to be changed to the following:
    myString = "RULE2=IF(EVENT='Veteran''s Day','Day 1','Day 2', MEASURE1.LAG)";

That is all text except those within single quotes are trimmed of extra spaces and turned to upperCase().
I thought I could use regex to extract [Rule2,if,event] and use String.replaceAll() et al. No luck. It is the third day today. My head has stopped working now. Please help.
Would be grateful for any pointers.

Space after comma should also be trimmed right?

@anubhava yes. Updated the example. Thanks!

ok I think you still missed space after'Day 2', in the expected output. I have posted a solution below, see if that works out for you.

You may consider following regex based solution for your task:
final Pattern QRX = Pattern.compile("'[^']*'|([^']+)");

String s = "Rule2 = if(event = 'Veteran''s Day', 'Day 1', 'Day 2', Measure1.Lag)";
s = QRX.matcher(s).replaceAll(m ->
   m.group(1) != null ? m.group().replace(" ", "").toUpperCase() : m.group()
);
System.out.println(s);
//=> RULE2=IF(EVENT='Veteran''s Day','Day 1','Day 2',MEASURE1.LAG)

Regex pattern '[^']*'|([^']+) matches either a single quoted string or any 1+ characters that doesn't contain a ' in the 1st capture group.
Code Demo

Here I use a a pattern for '...' or '... or non-apostrophes.
Then that replaceAll will work, alternating uppercasing parts.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("('[^']*('|$)|[^']+)");
String myString = "Rule2 = if(event = 'Veteran''s Day', 'Day1', 'Day2')";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(myString);
String s = m.replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().startsWith("'")
                              ? mr.group() : mr.group().toUpperCase());

Shorter would be '.*?' but this is clear and does not clash with an odd number of apostrophes

The lambda expression should use the mr parameter instead of accessing m. Further, this code does not consider the desired trimming. A solution would be Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'[^']*'|(\\S+)\\s*"); and pattern.matcher(myString) .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().startsWith("'")? mr.group(): mr.group(1).toUpperCase())

The m.group was an accident, and it worked; corrected it. On extra spaces you are right and that is a useful hint. Primarily I wanted to show working with the Matcher#replaceAll(Function).

@Holger if we have "if (event1 = 'a' and event2 = 'b')" then your suggestion would result in "IF(EVENT1='a' ANDEVENT2='b')" which is obviously not what the OP would want.

@k314159 maybe. The OP did not provide enough information to determine whether this is a problem or not. Their “specification by example” just says “remove all white-space”.

I think using the Pattern class along with Regex would solve your problem.
Below is the example implementation:
// Regular expression to match text within single quotes
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'"); // The java.util.regex.Pattern class
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); // The java.util.regex.Matcher class

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int lastIndex = 0;

while (matcher.find()) {
    String outsideQuotes = input.substring(lastIndex, matcher.start());
    result.append(outsideQuotes.replaceAll("\\s+", "").toUpperCase());

    result.append(input.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));

    lastIndex = matcher.end();
}

// Append the remaining text after the last match
if (lastIndex < input.length()) {
    result.append(input.substring(lastIndex).replaceAll("\\s+", "").toUpperCase());
}

// result.toString() is the final String result.

Hope this helps.

In JDK21 you might make use of splitWithDelimiters which pulls out all quoted components to an array. Then you can replace all spaces in even index positions and re-join each component:
static String reformat(String s) {
    var arr = s.splitWithDelimiters("'(.*?)'", -1);
    for (int i = 0; i< arr.length; i+=2) {
        arr[i]=arr[i].replace(" ", "").toUpperCase();
    }
    return String.join("", arr);
}

The above can be re-worked to one liner:
static String reformat(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.splitWithDelimiters("'(.*?)'", -1))
          .map(x -> x.startsWith("'") ? x : x.replace(" ", "").toUpperCase())
          .collect(Collectors.joining());
}


Here is one way.
The data
String text = "Rule2 = if(event = 'Veteran''s Day', 'Day1', 'Day2')";
String desiredResult = "RULE2=IF(EVENT='Veteran''s Day', 'Day1', 'Day2')";

The process
text = text.replaceAll("'.*|\\s", "").toUpperCase()
        + text.substring(text.indexOf('\''));

The result
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println(text.equals(desiredResult));

Prints
RULE2=IF(EVENT='Veteran''s Day', 'Day1', 'Day2')
true

The Explanation

Remove everything from the first single quote onward, removing white space and converting to uppercase.
Prepend that to the substring beginning with the first single quote.

